# Release pipeline to Prod is just queued, not starting to deploy- devops Azure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-function-app

I have created a release pipeline in my devops for function app. It has stage for Test deployment(manually triggered) and prod deployment trigger set to "After Stage- Test". It also has pre-deployment approval set up.
On manually triggering the release (multiple stages). Test gets deployed but Prod stage is just queued. I do not see any option to do the approval too. How to have prod also deployed and not just queued? Am i missing something, please help?
The screenshots will make more sense, attaching screenshot from devops -

[image: prod pre-deployment condition]

prod pre-deployment approval

[image: pre-deployment approval]

screenshot of Release where Prod is queued-

[image: Prod is queued]

Comment: If you click into the stage log does it tell you what it is waiting on?  Is your stage targeting an agent or deployment group.  Usually, when it stuck like this, it probably means whatever capability or target you've defined is not available.

Comment: Something is not right. On the last screenshot Prod should be connected to be after Test with a line like in the first screenshot i belive. Also possible that you are not in the approver group and cant see the aprove button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you were seeing the Prod was queued is because there was a deployment to Prod was waiting for approval in a previous release.See below two screenshot.

the Deployment to App2 is appending for approval in release-47. So that in release-48 the deployment to App2 was shown as queued

[image]

[image]

You should check the deployment to Prod was pending for approval in which release, and approve or cancel to deployment to Prod in the previous releases.

Or you can set the `Deployment queue settings` for Prod stage to check the option  `Deploy the latest and cancel the others`. So that when you create a new release, all the previous pending approval / queued deployment to Prod wil be cancelled, only the newest deployment to Prod will be showing as pending for approval.

[image]